# Converting Excel files to text files

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert an Excel file to a text file, with every column header and row values to be surrounded by "" and the delimiter is ;.

I found a code which works to a certain extent. What doesn't work is the last column in Excel has no values.

On Row 2, the second last column has a value "1/1/2010".

- I expect the flow to be "1/1/2010";"" .
- I get "1/1/2010".

This is wrong and the upload website is rejecting it.

1. How do I fix the VBA code?
2. By default it saves in Documents folder.
   How do I save the txt file to a particular path\folder?

```vb
Public Sub OutputQuotedCSV()
    Const QSTR As String = """"
    Dim myRecord As Range
    Dim myField As Range
    Dim nFileNum As Long
    Dim sOut As String
        
    nFileNum = FreeFile
    Open "File2.txt" For Output As #nFileNum
    For Each myRecord In Range("A1:A" & _
      Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        With myRecord
            For Each myField In Range(.Cells(1), _
              Cells(.Row, 256).End(xlToLeft))
                sOut = sOut & ";" & QSTR & _
                  Replace(myField.Text, QSTR, QSTR & QSTR) & QSTR
            Next myField
            Print #nFileNum, Mid(sOut, 2)
            sOut = Empty
        End With
    Next myRecord
    Close #nFileNum
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your answer. I pasted the code you provided. But it gives me a notepad file with just this - "".. There is no data. Is there any other step I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is only running up to the end of each row's occupied cells (because it runs xlToLeft on every line)

you can do this instead - get the line length from the header row and use that for each row:

```
Public Sub OutputQuotedCSV()
    Const QSTR As String = """"
    Const SEP As String = ";"
    Dim myRecord As Range
    Dim myField As Range
    Dim nFileNum As Long, rngOut As Range
    Dim sOut As String, s As String
    Dim lstRow As Long, lstCol As Long

    nFileNum = FreeFile
    Open "C:\Tester\File2.txt" For Output As #nFileNum

    'find the range to be exported
    With ActiveSheet
        lstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lstCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rngOut = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(lstRow, lstCol))
    End With

    'loop over each row in the export range
    For Each myRecord In rngOut.Rows

        sOut = ""
        s = "" 'no separator for first record
        'loop over each cell in the row
        For Each myField In myRecord.Cells
            'quote the cell text, escaping any embedded " with ""
            sOut = sOut & s & QSTR & Replace(myField.Text, QSTR, QSTR & QSTR) & QSTR
            s = SEP 'add the separator for subsequent fields
        Next myField
        Print #nFileNum, sOut

    Next myRecord

    Close #nFileNum
End Sub
```